# Vite Chrome Extension: npm run dev works but npm run build throws an error in content script

Tags: google-chrome-extension, vuejs3, vite, chrome-extension-manifest-v3, content-script

#### Question

I think the error occurs due to the difference in output (which naturally occurs). I'd like to ask how to resolve the issue below in the build environment.

I would like to ask if there are any settings to be done for the Content Script when building.

#### Summary:

When running npm run build, the generated output (dist) causes an error when loading the content script after uploading it to chrome://extension and running the extension.

When running npm run dev, the generated output (dist) works as intended after re-uploading it to chrome://extension and running the extension.

Error: Error occurs when loading Content Script in the build environment (see attached image below)

- Popup, Background working ✅
- Current build tool: Vite 3.2.3
- In development environment, crxjs is running (https://crxjs.dev/vite-plugin/)
  crxjs allows using Vite's HMR, static asset import, etc. without separate settings in the vite      configuration

Vite.config.js

```
import { defineConfig } from "vite";
import vue from "@vitejs/plugin-vue";
import { crx } from "@crxjs/vite-plugin";
import manifest from "./public/manifest.json";
import tailwindcss from "tailwindcss";

// https://vitejs.dev/config/
export default defineConfig({
  plugins: [
    vue(),
    crx({ manifest }),
    tailwindcss(),
  ],
});
```

I suspect that it might be because crxjs runs during the development environment (npm run dev), and the output of npm run dev works normally when uploaded to chrome://extension.

Error log:

**TypeError: Cannot read properties of null (reading 'define')
at _plugin-vue_export-helper.73f82c73.js:5:70
at _plugin-vue_export-helper.73f82c73.js:5:85
at __decorate (_plugin-vue_export-helper.73f82c73.js:1:74665)
at _plugin-vue_export-helper.73f82c73.js:267:4095**

#### Occurrence

Build the extension using the npm run build command
Upload the dist folder, which is the build output folder, to chrome://extension
Popup, background (service worker) work normally
Error occurs when trying to load the Content Script

#### Strange point

-Run the npm run dev command in the state where the above error occurred.

-Upload the dist folder, which is the build output folder created by the npm run dev command, to chrome://extension

-No error occurs ❌ (such as mounting the Vue Instance to the shadow DOM through the content script, works without a problem)

-Content script load successful ✅

#### The difference in output(dist) between npm run build and npm run dev

- npm run build

```
dist
 ┣ assets
 ┃ ┣ App.ffc4b17d.js
 ┃ ┣ Email.a32598ba.js
 ┃ ┣ Face.4b9e1197.js
 ┃ ┣ GoBack.11e3c52b.js
 ┃ ┣ LoginLoading.d1a67a36.js
 ┃ ┣ Logo.977a9321.png
 ┃ ┣ Logo.c227c976.js
 ┃ ┣ Record.vue-loader.65a1bb18.js
 ┃ ┣ Record.vue.12705994.js
 ┃ ┣ SignUp.d5759d01.js
 ┃ ┣ Signin.a9d92e4a.js
 ┃ ┣ TermsAndService.aa235f09.js
 ┃ ┣ VerificationView.ee9fb499.js
 ┃ ┣ _plugin-vue_export-helper.0af1f5dd.css
 ┃ ┣ _plugin-vue_export-helper.73f82c73.js
 ┃ ┣ api.c2cdd890.js
 ┃ ┣ background.js.c16cf37f.js
 ┃ ┣ contentScript.js-loader.637b20f6.js
 ┃ ┣ contentScript.js.b0d2b17a.js
 ┃ ┣ countdown_5s.051abdac.mp3
 ┃ ┣ index.2989bb6f.css
 ┃ ┣ index.cd44672f.js
 ┃ ┣ index.html.af78079e.js
 ┃ ┗ utils.b227fbf4.js
 ┣ dist
 ┃ ┗ index.css
 ┣ public
 ┃ ┗ index.css
 ┣ src
 ┃ ┣ assets
 ┃ ┃ ┗ tailwind.css
 ┃ ┣ content-scripts
 ┃ ┃ ┣ contentScript.js
 ┃ ┃ ┣ permission.html
 ┃ ┃ ┗ permission.js
 ┃ ┗ index.css
 ┣ Logo.png
 ┣ cam.png
 ┣ icon.png
 ┣ index.css
 ┣ index.html
 ┣ manifest.json
 ┣ random.vue
 ┣ screen.png
 ┣ screencam.png
 ┗ service-worker-loader.js
```

- npm run dev

```
dist
 ┣ assets
 ┃ ┣ App.ffc4b17d.js
 ┃ ┣ Email.a32598ba.js
 ┃ ┣ Face.4b9e1197.js
 ┃ ┣ GoBack.11e3c52b.js
 ┃ ┣ LoginLoading.d1a67a36.js
 ┃ ┣ Logo.977a9321.png
 ┃ ┣ Logo.c227c976.js
 ┃ ┣ Record.vue-loader.65a1bb18.js
 ┃ ┣ Record.vue.12705994.js
 ┃ ┣ SignUp.d5759d01.js
 ┃ ┣ Signin.a9d92e4a.js
 ┃ ┣ TermsAndService.aa235f09.js
 ┃ ┣ VerificationView.ee9fb499.js
 ┃ ┣ _plugin-vue_export-helper.0af1f5dd.css
 ┃ ┣ _plugin-vue_export-helper.73f82c73.js
 ┃ ┣ api.c2cdd890.js
 ┃ ┣ background.js.c16cf37f.js
 ┃ ┣ contentScript.js-loader.637b20f6.js
 ┃ ┣ contentScript.js.b0d2b17a.js
 ┃ ┣ countdown_5s.051abdac.mp3
 ┃ ┣ index.2989bb6f.css
 ┃ ┣ index.cd44672f.js
 ┃ ┣ index.html.af78079e.js
 ┃ ┣ precontroller-f5140eea.js
 ┃ ┗ utils.b227fbf4.js
 ┣ dist
 ┃ ┗ index.css
 ┣ public
 ┃ ┗ index.css
 ┣ src
 ┃ ┣ assets
 ┃ ┃ ┣ Logo.png
 ┃ ┃ ┣ Logo.png__import.js
 ┃ ┃ ┣ cam.png
 ┃ ┃ ┣ cam.png__import.js
 ┃ ┃ ┣ countdown_5s.mp3
 ┃ ┃ ┣ countdown_5s.mp3__import.js
 ┃ ┃ ┣ recording.json
 ┃ ┃ ┣ recording.json__import.js
 ┃ ┃ ┣ recording_end.mp3
 ┃ ┃ ┣ recording_end.mp3__import.js
 ┃ ┃ ┣ recording_start.mp3
 ┃ ┃ ┣ recording_start.mp3__import.js
 ┃ ┃ ┣ screen.png
 ┃ ┃ ┣ screen.png__import.js
 ┃ ┃ ┣ screencam.png
 ┃ ┃ ┣ screencam.png__import.js
 ┃ ┃ ┗ tailwind.css
 ┃ ┣ content-scripts
 ┃ ┃ ┣ contentScript.js
 ┃ ┃ ┣ contentScript.js-loader.js
 ┃ ┃ ┣ contentScript.js.js
 ┃ ┃ ┣ permission.html
 ┃ ┃ ┗ permission.js
 ┃ ┣ services
 ┃ ┃ ┣ api.js.js
 ┃ ┃ ┣ axios.js.js
 ┃ ┃ ┗ utils.js.js
 ┃ ┣ store
 ┃ ┃ ┗ index.js.js
 ┃ ┣ views
 ┃ ┃ ┣ Record.vue-loader.js
 ┃ ┃ ┣ Record.vue.js
 ┃ ┃ ┣ Timer.vue.js
 ┃ ┃ ┗ Timer.vue__vue_type--style_index--0_scoped--73260592_lang.css.js
 ┃ ┣ VueContent.vue.js
 ┃ ┣ firebase.config.js.js
 ┃ ┗ index.css
 ┣ vendor
 ┃ ┣ .vite-deps-@heroicons_vue_24_outline.js__v--c2b1439f.js
 ┃ ┣ .vite-deps-@heroicons_vue_24_solid.js__v--c2b1439f.js
 ┃ ┣ .vite-deps-@lottiefiles_lottie-player.js__v--c2b1439f.js
 ┃ ┣ .vite-deps-@twind_core.js__v--c2b1439f.js
 ┃ ┣ .vite-deps-@twind_preset-autoprefix.js__v--c2b1439f.js
 ┃ ┣ .vite-deps-@twind_preset-tailwind.js__v--c2b1439f.js
 ┃ ┣ .vite-deps-@vespaiach_axios-fetch-adapter.js__v--c2b1439f.js
 ┃ ┣ .vite-deps-axios.js__v--c2b1439f.js
 ┃ ┣ .vite-deps-chunk-D5XN23UX.js__v--c2b1439f.js
 ┃ ┣ .vite-deps-chunk-FBGRIXZF.js__v--c2b1439f.js
 ┃ ┣ .vite-deps-chunk-FVZHS5AO.js__v--c2b1439f.js
 ┃ ┣ .vite-deps-chunk-QO6ZHO7P.js__v--c2b1439f.js
 ┃ ┣ .vite-deps-chunk-TWLJ45QX.js__v--c2b1439f.js
 ┃ ┣ .vite-deps-chunk-UYBEYQUL.js__v--c2b1439f.js
 ┃ ┣ .vite-deps-construct-style-sheets-polyfill.js__v--c2b1439f.js
 ┃ ┣ .vite-deps-firebase_app.js__v--c2b1439f.js
 ┃ ┣ .vite-deps-firebase_auth.js__v--c2b1439f.js
 ┃ ┣ .vite-deps-vue.js__v--c2b1439f.js
 ┃ ┣ .vite-deps-vuex.js__v--c2b1439f.js
 ┃ ┣ .vite-deps-worker-timers.js__v--c2b1439f.js
 ┃ ┣ crx-client-port.js
 ┃ ┣ id-__x00__plugin-vue:export-helper.js
 ┃ ┣ vite-client.js
 ┃ ┣ vite-dist-client-env.mjs.js
 ┃ ┗ webcomponents-custom-elements.js
 ┣ Logo.png
 ┣ cam.png
 ┣ config.json
 ┣ config.json__import.js
 ┣ icon.png
 ┣ index.css
 ┣ index.html
 ┣ manifest.json
 ┣ random.vue
 ┣ screen.png
 ┣ screencam.png
 ┣ service-worker-loader.js
 ┣ twind.config.cjs
 ┗ twind.config.cjs__import.js
```

I have tried several vite configurations.